# How to get two columns of data (facility and city) from an online database?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I'm new to XPath and having trouble retrieving the *Facility* and *City* data from a table. My intention is to get the four facility names and their cities from the bottom left table on this [webpage](https://www.peeringdb.com/ix/863) on Google Sheets. Being the novice I am, I use Edge's Inspect function to find the "overarching" XPath of this table that led to the formula "=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML("https://www.peeringdb.com/ix/863","/html/body/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXJs3.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXJs3.png)/div[1](https://www.peeringdb.com/ix/863)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXJs3.png)/div[1](https://www.peeringdb.com/ix/863)/div[3]"))".

[GSheets Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXJs3.png)

This is, however, not ideal as the facilities aren't sorted into separate rows. What would be the XPath syntax for IMPORTXML to separate the Facility and City names into their respective rows? If that's too hard to achieve, I don't mind including the *Country* column as well even if it's redundant. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A2

```
=importxml(A1;"//div[@class='facility']")
```

In B2

```
=importxml(A1;"//div[@class='city']")
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thanks Mike!

Comment: Thx for your feedback, upvote and close the topic

Comment: Hey @Mike, I applied your formula =IMPORTXML("https://discover.cloudscene.com/data-center/united-kingdom/london/telehouse-telehouse-london-docklands-north-north-two","//div[@class='j1lbxw-0 sc-1pnc2j7-0 jHZiQS JgKwX']") to get the # of Service Providers from this [webpage](https://discover.cloudscene.com/data-center/united-kingdom/london/telehouse-telehouse-london-docklands-north-north-two) but it didn't work. Do you mind teaching me what I did wrong?

Comment: Because the web page is built by javascript on customer side, not on server side ... see how to detect this here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun. So you will not be able to fetch data with importxml function.

Comment: Oh dear, is there no way to grab data from this page using GSheets IMPORT functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess not! I didn't find any json inside the webpage like others ... (yahoo for instance).

Comment: Oh :( 
Thanks nonetheless

Comment: Hi @mike-steelson Sir, sorry to bother you; I was wondering if you could help with some IMPORTXML problems I came across (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69318890/how-to-format-aws-regions-azs-data-into-table)

Comment: ok, i will take a close look tomorrow morning (paris time)

Comment: Hi Mike, as a follow-up to this question, do you mind helping me check what's wrong with my formula in this new question (same website; different data to grab this time)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353452/trouble-retrieving-numbers-using-importxml

Comment: ok, done with a more complete answer to get all data from the table

Answer (score 1):

With xpath 1.0, you can probably only do something like this:

Assuming your url is in A1, enter in B1

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='list-facilities']//div[@class='row item']//div[@class='facility']")
```

and in B2

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='list-facilities']//div[@class='row item']//div[@class='city']")
```

You should get

```
Cogeco Peer 1 Vancouver 21 North        Vancouver
Cologix VAN2                    Vancouver
Cologix VAN3                     Vancouver
Harbour Centre Vancouver        Vancouver
```

which is close to what I think you are after.