# How to format AWS regions/AZs data into table?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to turn the Region, AZs and Year Launched data on the [AWS global page infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/) into a table with three columns. I was very close when I used the formula

`=IMPORTXML("https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/","//div[@class='lb-rtxt']//p")`

but the table is missing *US East (Northern Virginia) Region*

[image]

Why did this happen and how can I fix it? Also, what can I do to remove the redundant text like *Map Key*, *Regions*, *Edge Locations*, etc.? I only need "...(Region)", "AZs:..." and "Launched ...".

Finally, if possible, how can I put "Edge locations", "AWS Local Zones" and "Regional Edge Caches" from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?p=ugi&l=na&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc) into their own (three) separate columns? The closest I could get was

`=IMPORTXML("https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?p=ugi&l=na&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc","//div[@class='lb-rtxt']//p[1]/text()")`

[image]

Far from correct

I used TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(...),";") to separate the cities but what happened instead was only the text *"Reliable, low latency and high throughput network connectivity"* remained.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the locations, in A1

```
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?p=ugi&l=na&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc
```

in A2

```
//div[@class='lb-rtxt']/p[1]
```

and finally

```
=query(arrayformula(flatten(trim(substitute(split(query(importxml($A$1,A2),"select Col2 where Col2 is not null "),";"),":","")))),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: Hi Mike, tried your formula for Edge Locations and it works fine except for " : Ashburn, VA (6)" which I can't get rid of " : " for my purposes. See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QtYjgp2u8OAE4tBO2aoOeMl_OUFQVxlPZg_dEWX1Ouc/edit#gid=120841771 for a better idea of what I mean. 

Actually, is there a way to get rid of "Regional Edge caches?" Might not have to count them for my research.

Comment: Actually, ignore the second question. I got rid of "Regional Edge caches" by making A2 //div[@class='lb-txt-none lb-txt-18 lb-txt']|//div[@class='lb-rtxt']/p[1]. Now I just need to remove the space and colon from Ashburn

Comment: ok, I have updated the query / you can also simplify the xpath

Comment: Very nice, this got rid of the space and colon in Ashburn. Thanks a lot.
Is there no way to get the Regions, AZs, and Year Launched by IMPORTXML and not script though?

Comment: I will have a look at it ...

Comment: See the new answer

Comment: Hi Mike, mind helping me with sth (possibly) simple? The formula =IMPORTXML("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-locations","//tr/td[2]/text()") pulls city names from both the Microsoft and Partners tables when I only want names from the former. The table XPaths are: 

/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/main/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text() &

/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()

Comment: The formula came back empty, however, when I applied =IMPORTXML("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-locations","//div[4]//tr/td[2]/text()"). May I know how I should structure the xpath-query instead?

Comment: Just try `=importhtml(url,"table",1)`

Comment: to retrieve only the towns `=query(arrayformula(flatten(split(query(importhtml(url,"table",1),"select Col2"),char(10)))),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null")`

Comment: another solution `=query(flatten(importxml(url,"//table[1]//tr/td[2]")),"select * where Col1 is not null")`

Comment: Thanks, Mike! The impression I got from most of your solutions so far is that IMPORTXML() is so limited that QUERY() is often needed to arrive at satisfactory solutions

Comment: IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML are the basic formulas, and then you have to complete / encapsulate with query to get the target result

Comment: Hi Mike, are you able to tell why IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML aren't working on https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/cloud/data-regions/ and https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/overview?topic=overview-locations#data-centers, which are both public URLs? I keep getting the "could not fetch URL" error message.

Comment: no way! no answer! I suspect Oracle to ignore requests posted by Google (since through GSheets, it is Google that requires data). In excel I have quite no problem (in excel, it is the terminal computer on client side that requests data).

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping to not have to turn to Excel but thanks

Answer (score 1):

A solution with script can give you a database

```
function listOfLocations(url) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|<br>|&nbsp;|&amp;|  )/gm," ");
  var result=[]
  result.push(['region','type','location'])
  var regions = source.split('<div class="lb-txt-none lb-txt-18 lb-txt">')
  var n1=0
  regions.forEach(function(region){
    if (n1++>0) {
      var myRegion = region.split('</div>')[0].trim()
      var types = region.split('<p>')
      var n2=0
      types.forEach(function(type){
        if (n2++>0) {
          try{
            var myType = type.split('<b>')[1].split('</b>')[0].trim()
            var locations = type.split('</b>')[1].split('</p>')[0].split(';')
            locations.forEach(function(location){
              var myLocation = location.trim()
              if (myLocation != '' && (myLocation.indexOf('CloudFront') == -1)){
                result.push([myRegion,myType,myLocation])
              }
            })
          }
          catch(e){}
        }
      })
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

in A1:

```
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?p=ugi&l=na&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc
```

in A2:

```
=listOfLocations(A1)
```

Comment: Sorry Mike, is there a way to solve this using only GSheet's IMPORT functions? My team isn't comfortable with running a script on the workbook, just like how some firms bar the use of macros on company laptops.

Comment: Okay. What do you think of my other answer?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the other answer also relies on script since I didn't see the use of formulas except in the third block. Can you show me how the other answer works?

Answer (score 1):

For Regions, AZs, and Year Launched

```
=query(importxml("https://aws.amazon.com/fr/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/","//div[@class='lb-rtxt']//p"),"select Col1,Col3,Col5,Col7,Col9 where Col5 is not null")
```

or ...

```
=query(importxml("https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/?nc1=h_ls","//div[@class='lb-rtxt']//b|//div[@class='lb-rtxt']//i"),"select * where Col1 like 'Launched%' or Col1 like '%Region%' ")
```

.

Comment: This sure looks cleaner than my formula =FILTER(IMPORTXML("https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/","//div[@class='lb-rtxt']/p"),REGEXMATCH(N3:N76,":")), where N3:N76 is the column containing "Availability Zones : X"

Your formula is missing Northern Virginia as a region tho :/

Comment: because this region is not encapsulated par <p>, so the xpath `//div[@class='lb-rtxt']//p` is not sufficient!

Comment: i put a complement ...

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike!