# Trouble retrieving numbers using IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

does anyone know how to grab the # of networks (one at a time in each cell) from a list on this [page](https://www.peeringdb.com/fac/167)? After trial and error, I think `=IMPORTXML("https://www.peeringdb.com/fac/167","//div[@data-filter-value='BGP.Exchange' and @'participants']")` should be most "correct," but the formula isn't working...What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=importxml($A$1,"//div[@data-filter-value='"&trim(A2)&"']/../..//div[@class='participants']")
```

[image]

Another solution

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(trim(A2),trim(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='scrollable']//div")),3,0))
```

Comment: Sorry Mike, I should've clarified: what if I want only one number at a time in each cell? https://i.imgur.com/2NTneRN.png. Thus the need to //div[@data-filter-value='BGP.Exchange'

Comment: ok, but I think that you could fetch all values at once, I have updated my proposal.

Comment: Hi Mike, is there a way for the formula to include //div[@data-filter-value='BGP.Exchange'? If you go to another facility, the IXs either change sequence or are totally different. This is why I have to grab the network quantity of each IX separately.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, "div class=exchange" and "div class = participants" are at the same div hierarchy, requiring a "two-way lookup" IMPORTXML to grab the number of networks. I think =IMPORTXML("https://www.peeringdb.com/fac/167", "//div[@data-filter-value='BGP.exchange' and @class='participants']") is close but the formula isn't working :(

https://i.imgur.com/POmM4Ph.png

Comment: ok, the solution could be `=importxml($A$1,"//div[@data-filter-value='"&A2&"']/../..//div[@class='participants']")` : when you are at the same level, use /.. to go one step higher

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, solution =importxml($A$1,"//div[@data-filter-value='"&A2&"']/../..//div[@class='participants']") is exactly it but stuck on loading when I apply it in my model. It works fine when I load it in a blank sheet though. Any idea why this is the case and how I can get it working? https://i.imgur.com/vu0Rbag.png

Comment: Check if you have extra space before or after your article, change A2 to `trim(A2)`. Howerver, why not try `=arrayformula(vlookup(trim(A2),trim(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='scrollable']//div")),3,0))` ?

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Many thanks, Mike!

Comment: Hi Mike, can I ask you sth? When I removed the arrayformula() component, value "25" turned into a #REF (VLOOKUP evals to out of bounds range) error msg. I understand your formula up to the VLOOKUP level (match IX name in 1st col to return corresp value in 3rd col of XML table), but can you explain to me what arrayformula is doing here?

Comment: arrayformula will expand the trim function to the full array, if you just write `=TRIM(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='scrollable']//div"))` you will only fetch one value in one column, therefor the vlookup will not be able to find any third column `=ARRAYFORMULA(vlookup(_____,_____,3,0))` and will give you #REF! error.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't VLOOKUP come before ARRAYFORMULA rather than after?

Comment: yes, the result will be the same; but ... in my proposal you can also replace `trim(A2)` with `trim(A2:A)` to retrieve all data at one time with just one website call, that's why l put before ... `=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,vlookup(trim(A2:A),trim(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='scrollable']//div")),3,0)))`

Comment: Interesting, when I tried =vlookup(trim(IX), arrayformula(trim(importxml(URL,"//div[@class='scrollable']//div"))),3,0), it works fine for my purposes and it's easier to explain to my colleagues what I'm doing. So arrayformula() simply "rebuilds" the table after you "destroy" it using trim(). Got it and thanks for patiently explaining!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='scrollable']/div"), 
 "select Col3 where Col3 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry player0, I should've clarified: what if I want only one number at a time in each cell? i.imgur.com/2NTneRN.png . Thus the need to //div[@data-filter-value='BGP.Exchange

Comment: @stack91 see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10PoGCgoczlcEEWhQHnhJXPTzJ85NJ2OuEQKQ-kPyukM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi player0, is there a way for the formula to include //div[@data-filter-value='BGP.Exchange'? If you go to another facility, the IXs either change sequence or are totally different. This is why I have to grab the network quantity of each IX separately. This formula, =INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='scrollable']/div"), 2, 3)
, for e.g., does not grab the BGP.Exchange number at a different facility.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, "div class=exchange" and "div class = participants" are at the same div hierarchy, requiring a "two-way lookup" IMPORTXML to grab the number of networks. I think =IMPORTXML("peeringdb.com/fac/167", "//div[@data-filter-value='BGP.exchange' and @class='participants']") is close but the formula isn't working... i.imgur.com/POmM4Ph.png

Comment: @stack91 well not rly. they are on same level of hierarchy eg. there is no direct link between them. the only common element they share is `<div class="row item"` what you want to accomplish would be possible only if value 25 (participants element) would be under BGP.exchange (exchange element) see the structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UJSr.png you can do only OR logic like this: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.peeringdb.com/fac/167", "//div[@data-filter-value='BGP.Exchange'] | //div[@class='participants']")` but as you can see this wont help you either

Comment: @player0 - 
in this case you can get 2 steps higher by `/../ ..` then check the number of participants